# WebdriverIO automation test give me this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseUrl'

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

This is the console result:

```
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0] Running: chrome (v97.0.4692.99) on mac os x
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0] Session ID: 12a9eb48c2c5c3efd4a7edabad5a153c
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0]
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0] » /test/specs/gtb-ui.ts
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0] /get-the-box
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0]    ✖ "before all" hook for /get-the-box
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0]
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0] 1 failing (75ms)
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0]
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0] 1) /get-the-box "before all" hook for /get-the-box
[chrome 97.0.4692.99 mac os x #0-0] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseUrl')
```

Here is my tsconfig.js file:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "./*.js",
    "src", 
    "wdio.conf.ts"  ]
}
```

And here is my test case code:

```
import GetTheBoxPage from '../pageobjects/gtb.page';

describe('/get-the-box', () => {
  before(async () => {
    await GetTheBoxPage.open();
  });

  it('can view hero banner', async () => {
    // await expect(GetTheBoxPage.heroBanner).toBeExisting();
    await expect (GetTheBoxPage.heroBanner).toBeVisible();
    // await expect(GetTheBoxPage.heroBannerGtbButton).toBeExisting();
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.heroBannerGtbButton).toBeVisible();
  });

  it('click gtb cta in hero and get scrolled to form', async () => {
    await GetTheBoxPage.heroBannerGtbButton.click();
  });

  it('can view customize section', async () => {
    const customizeIsOpen = await GetTheBoxPage.customizeSection;
    if (customizeIsOpen) {
      await expect(GetTheBoxPage.customizeTitle).toBeExisting();
      expect(await GetTheBoxPage.customizeTitle.getText()).toBe('Choose Your First Product');
      await expect(GetTheBoxPage.customizeSkipButton).toBeExisting();
      expect(await GetTheBoxPage.customizeSkipButton.getText()).toBe('Skip This and Choose After I Pay');
    }
  });

  it('can view how it works section', async () => {
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.howItWorksSection).toBeExisting();
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.howItWorksTitle).toBeExisting();
    expect(await GetTheBoxPage.howItWorksTitle.getText()).toBe('How It Works');
  });

  it('can view plans section', async () => {
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.plansSection).toBeExisting();
  });

  // need to account for all form inputs
  it('can view form', async () => {
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.formSection).toBeExisting();
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.emailInput).toBeExisting();
    expect(await GetTheBoxPage.emailInput.getValue()).toBe('');
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.passwordInput).toBeExisting();
    expect(await GetTheBoxPage.passwordInput.getValue()).toBe('');
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.shipCountrySelect).toBeExisting();
    expect(await GetTheBoxPage.shipCountrySelect.getValue()).toBe('US');
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.shipStateSelect).toBeExisting();
    expect(await GetTheBoxPage.shipStateSelect.getValue()).toBe('');
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.shipZipInput).toBeExisting();
    expect(await GetTheBoxPage.shipZipInput.getValue()).toBe('');
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.orderTheBoxButton).toBeExisting();
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.orderTheBoxButton).toBeDisabled();
  });

  // need to account for all form inputs
  it('enable order the box button', async () => {
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.orderTheBoxButton).toBeExisting();
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.orderTheBoxButton).toBeDisabled();
    // await GetTheBoxPage.signUp('test@fabfitfun.com', 'Password123!',
    //   '90031', 'Jeannie', 'Test', 4111111111111111, 12, 30, 123, 90031);
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.shipCountrySelect).toBeExisting();
    await GetTheBoxPage.shipCountrySelect.click();
    await GetTheBoxPage.shipCountrySelect.selectByVisibleText('United States');
    await expect(GetTheBoxPage.shipStateSelect).toBeExisting();
    await GetTheBoxPage.shipStateSelect.click();
    await GetTheBoxPage.shipStateSelect.selectByVisibleText('California');
    // await expect(GetTheBoxPage.orderTheBoxButton).not.toBeDisabled();
  });
});
```

One of the errors are

**» /test/specs/gtb-ui.ts
/get-the-box
✖ "before all" hook for /get-the-box

1. /get-the-box "before all" hook for /get-the-box
   Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseUrl')**

I don't know how to solve that one, I'm pretty new at this but if anyone have some tips that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Your baseUrl is undefined. I would look at your `wdio.conf.js` file and check how you are defining it and make sure it's configured properly. You could also post your conf file and the test code you are running for some more detailed help.

Comment: the baseurl on the wdio.config.js is like this baseUrl: `[process.env.ENV],`

Comment: That should work, but in your command to run the tests you need to pass in the ENV. For example:
`ENV=http://www.google.com npm run test`. And this is a good resource for making sure the baseUrl is set up properly: [TestAutomationU WebdriverIO Adding Environments and Base URLs](https://testautomationu.applitools.com/webdriverio-tutorial/chapter6.3.html). If you go to the "Transcripted Summary" you can see the code snippets.

Comment: I'm using this command `ENV=dev npm run wdio`

Comment: Also thanks for that resource, I'm checking it right now!

Comment: No prob! I would look for a file like `urls.js` and check that the `dev` environment is configured as an option in there

Comment: I check everything, the urls are there, the config file is correct and the baseUrl is also properly written, so right now I'm lost haha We are trying to get some help from the devops team and see if we can't solve this issue.